# gmail for business session cookie not persisting

Tags: cookies, gmail, session-cookies

When I'm logged in to a google account, site responses contain this cookie:

```
set-cookie:SIDCC=xxx; expires=Mon, 27-Nov-2017 06:12:16 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; priority=high
```

However when I restart Chrome and visit same site, no cookie is sent. Why is that? I thought that `expires` makes it persistent.

Answer (score 0):

There and multiple cookies are generated by the server and cookies are stored on the browser.

There are few cookies are having the short expiry and some have the long expiry. If cookie gets expired (deleted from the browser) then the browser will not append that cookie in the request. So sever again set the cookie on the browser.
Since cookie are generated by the server and cookies are used by the server so whenever the server wants to set cookie it can change. Usually, some cookies are persistent and some are not persistent always.

So there will be a case some cookie is stored for a long time duration but server used to the keep on changing. So, In that case, it will set the cookie again.

As per your example, this SIDCC cookie is used by the google apps. So this cookie is kept on changing the other cookie like SID and HSID are not changing on browser reopen. There few cookies like NID, SAPISID, and Compass is also changing. The SAPISID is changing after the few transaction or after a particular transaction.